# Why and when should we use optional functions (in Swift)?

Tags: swift

I have following questions about an optional function:

```
@objc protocol SSRadioButtonControllerDelegate {
/**
    This function is called when a button is selected. If 'shouldLetDeSelect' is true, and a button is deselected, this function
is called with a nil.

*/
optional func didSelectButton(aButton: UIButton?)
}
```

1. What is an optional function? Why doesn't it have to declare the method? What is it for?
2. Why `@objc` protocol instead of `@protocol`?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID284

Answer (score 1):

The protocol tells the delegate that you have selected a UIButton.

The optional method to this protocol informs the delegate if the button is selectable.

We use the **@objc** attribute if we want to use an optional method in a Swift protocol.

```
@objc protocol SSRadioButtonControllerDelegate: class {
optional func shouldLetDeSelect(sender: SSRadioButtonController) -> Bool
func didSelectButton(sender: UIButton?)
}
```

This also means that a Swift struct or enum can no longer adopt this protocol. But it doesn't matter because you already made this a class protocol.

The @objc attribute does not seem Swift-y. So when we think we need an optional method in a Swift protocol what are our alternatives?

Move the optional method to a separate protocol:

```
protocol SSRadioButtonControllerDelegate: class {
func shouldLetDeSelect(sender: SSRadioButtonController) -> Bool
}
```

You can then optionally decide to adopt and implement this new delegate method in your master view controller.

```
controller.delegate = self
// Uncomment if we need to implement shouldLetDeSelect:
// controller.ButtonSelectionDelegate = self
```

Another approach is to provide a default implementation for the “optional” method in an extension. We can clean up the protocol definition by removing the @objc and optional attributes:

```
protocol SSRadioButtonControllerDelegate: class {
func shouldLetDeSelect(sender: SSRadioButtonController) -> Bool
func didSelectButton(sender: UIButton?)
}
```

The method is now mandatory and must be implemented somewhere.

```
extension SSRadioButtonControllerDelegate {
func shouldLetDeSelect(sender: SSRadioButtonController) -> Bool {
return true
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you using protocols in this condition which class you going to use protocol need to conform protocol.

**Protocols** can require specific instance methods and type methods to be implemented by conforming types. These methods are written as part of the protocol’s definition in exactly the same way as for normal instance and type methods, but without curly braces or a method body. Variadic parameters are allowed, subject to the same rules as for normal methods. Default values, however, cannot be specified for method parameters within a protocol’s definition.

**Optional** function not required for conformation delegate just like table view inside some required method and some optional function.You can use as per your requirement.

Class one

```
import UIKit

//Here you creating protocol
@objc protocol MangoDelegate {
    func eatmango()
    optional func donoteat()
}

class ProtocolController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: MangoDelegate?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

}
```

Class Second here using protocol

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , MangoDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    //MARK: - delegate method
    func eatmango(){

    }

}
```

In this code i am using only required function and option not conforming protocol.

without method conformation Protocol

[image]

@try to conform protocol with optional function here but again need conformation

[image]

try with Required function here

[image]

and tried with both function

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### What is optional function?

And optional function is a function declared in a protocol that does not have to be implemented by classes that conform to such protocol.

---

### Why doesn't it have to declare the method?

Well, because it's optional.

---

### What is it for?

*An example is probably the best way to answer this question.*

You have a protocol `Bird`.
*(Technically, this protocol ought to be a class, however this was the first example off the top of my head.)*

In this protocol, you have a required `eat()` and an optional `fly()`.

You have 2 classes implementing the protocol `Bird`: `Dodo` and `Eagle`. *(Again, technically, they ought to be subclasses of a class Bird, but this is just a simple example.)*

`Dodo` and `Eagle` both must implement `eat()`, because they *(hopefully)* both eat.

However, when it comes to flying, eagles do *(assuming both wings are functional)*, but dodos don't. So, you ought to implement `fly()` for `Eagle` but not for `Dodo`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the @objc but still have the benefit of optional functions, simply extend the protocol with empty (or default) implementations of the protocol functions, eg -

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {
    func myFunc()
}

extension MyProtocol {
    func myFunc() {
        // do nothing (or something...)
    }
}
```

This means you don't have to implement the function in your class